# AngularJS + ADAL.JS set Resource ID (Audience)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, azure, azure-active-directory, adal.js

How can I use `adal.js` in AngularJS to get a bearer token for the audience `https://management.azure.com` from my javascript code?

I have created a Client application in the AD and set its permissions to allow it to access the "Windows Azure Service Management API". My angularjs code is as follows:

```
adalService.init(
            {
                instance: "https://login.windows.net/",
                tenant: "<something>.onmicrosoft.com",
                clientId: "<some id>",
                cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
                redirectUri: 'http://localhost:63691/index.html#/configure',
                endpoints: {
                    /* 'target endpoint to be called': 'target endpoint's resource ID' */
                    'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions?api-version=2014-04-01': 'https://management.azure.com/'
                }
            },
            $httpProvider
        );
```

If I use the token received by this adalService in POSTMAN to call `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions?api-version=2014-04-01`, I get the following error:

```
The access token has been obtained from wrong audience or resource '<some id>'. 
It should exactly match (including forward slash) with one of the allowed audiences 'https://management.core.windows.net/','https://management.azure.com/'.
```

Answer (score 9):

Okay so I found the solution after going through the source code of ADAL.JS here. At line 137, it looks at `config.loginResource` to see if it has been set when passing the `config` object to the `init()` function.

**Putting it out there for anyone getting stuck:**

If you need your token to have the claim for “https://management.azure.com/” (or any other resource URI), you can set the audience when initializing the AuthenticationContext like so:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', 'adalAuthenticationServiceProvider', function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider, adalService) {
    adalService.init(
                {
                    instance: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
                    tenant: "<something>.onmicrosoft.com",
                    clientId: "<client-id>",
                    cacheLocation: 'localStorage', //optional
                    redirectUri: '<redirect-uri>',
                    loginResource: 'https://management.azure.com/' //to set AUDIENCE
                },
                $httpProvider
            );
}]);
```

Comment: Can I ask you how did you did this? I want to know why did not you use the endpoint in your adalService.init?

Comment: It got past the authentication with this, but now ran into endless loop or renewing the token.

Comment: @Jaanus I had gotten the same problem. If you wait long enough, you'll see it is not an infinite loop. It stops refreshing after a while. Sadly, I did not figure out why this happens.