# Azure Active Directory OpenIdConnect Refresh Interval

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I have an application hosted in Azure using Azure Active Directory and OpenIDConnect for authentication - generally all works well.  However I'm having an issue where some requests generate a call to https://login.microsoftonline.com/ and then on to the requested page - no password is requested.  I'm assuming that this is some kind of token refresh?

The problem is that the site uses a fair amount of ajax and these requests stop working because they get redirected to https://login.microsoftonline.com/  This happens after maybe 15 minutes, however the nbf and exp properties of the JWT token show a validity period of approximately an hour.

I've set the BackchannelTimeout property of OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions to 30 minutes, however this doesn't seem to have made any difference.

Can anyone offer any advice on what may be happening and the options to change or work around the behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question can be answered in the same way as this other thread: [MVC AD Azure Refresh Token via ADAL JavaScript Ajax and KnockoutJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32428929/mvc-ad-azure-refresh-token-via-adal-javascript-ajax-and-knockoutjs/32429127#32429127)

In short: the OpenId Connect middleware is designed to support redirect based web applications. Ajax calls are not well suited to be protected via cookies, and the issue you are experiencing is one of the reasons why. Javascript based API calls are better protected using tokens rather than cookies.
For some links that might provide an alternative approach, see the link above.

Answer (score 0):

I created a nuget package for .NET web applications which is refreshing the Azure Active Directory Token in the background.
More info: https://www.nuget.org/packages/RefreshTokenForAjaxRequest.Azure.ActiveDirectory/

Comment: This just does a post to a random URL, or is part of the setup supposed to be modifying your js to point at a url made specifically for the token refresh purpose